# I want to start 10 threads. main thread starts first thread, 1st thread starts 2nd and so on upto 10, but instead of 10 threads 19 threads created

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package testpkg;

public class ThreadOrdering {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRunnable[] threads = new MyRunnable[10];//index 0 represents thread 1;
        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
            threads[i] = new MyRunnable(i, threads);
        //threads[0] = new MyRunnable(0, threads);
        new Thread(threads[0]).start();  
     }
```

}

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    int threadNumber;
    MyRunnable[] threads;

    public MyRunnable(int threadNumber, MyRunnable[] threads) {
        this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
        this.threads = threads;
    }

    public void run() {
    synchronized (this) {
        if(this.threadNumber!=10)
            new Thread(threads[this.threadNumber]).start();
            this.threadNumber++;
    }
    System.out.println("the thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " with num " + this.threadNumber);
}
```

}

I actually should not be incrementing threadNumber, but if I don't it goes into a infinite loop, and if I do increment 19 threads are created instead of 10

Answer (score 2):

It's the `threadNumber++` that's causing duplicate threads to be started.
If you use `new Thread(threads[this.threadNumber+1]).start();` (and remove the `threadNumber++`) only 10 are started.

Let's examine the logic:

```
new Thread(threads[0]).start();  // Start the first thread

// Inside the first thread's run
if(0 != 10)
    new Thread(threads[0]).start(); // Oh noes, we restarted the first thread/runnable
this.threadNumber++; // We restarted the thread, AND incremented its threadnumber!

// Inside the first runnable's run AGAIN!
if(1 != 10)
    new Thread(threads[1]).start(); // NOW we started the second thread
this.threadNumber++; // First thread's threadnumber is now 2, but we didn't restart it so it won't run again
```

So every thread except for the last one (where `10 != 10` returns false) restarts itself once, giving you the total of 19 threads.

Comment: threadNumber is a field in each MyRunnable instance, hence incrementing it does not have any effect on a different thread/runnable.

Comment: @Robert Yes, *different*. However when you run the *same* runnable again, there is a clear effect which is described in my answer.